# Subscribe in the sub-component instead of pass atom as parameter. (Reagent/Re-frame)

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

What do you think? Which solution is more performance-efficient?

A) Subscribe to the re-frame db atom in the sub-component

B) Pass that atom as parameter to the sub-component.

Here is an example for A:

```
(defn- sub-1 [] (let [state (r/subscribe [:totoro])] (fn []))
(defn- sub-2 [] (let [state (r/subscribe [:totoro])] (fn []))
(defn- sub-3 [] (let [state (r/subscribe [:totoro])] (fn []))

(defn strawberry []
  [sub-1]
  [sub-2]
  [sub-3])
```

Example for B:

```
(defn- sub-1 [state] (fn [] @state))
(defn- sub-2 [state] (fn [] @state))
(defn- sub-3 [state] (fn [] @state))

(defn strawberry []
  (let [state (r/subscribe [:totoro])]
    (fn []
      [sub-1 state]
      [sub-2 state]
      [sub-3 state])))
```

Example for B/2:

```
(defn- sub-1 [state] (fn [] state))
(defn- sub-2 [state] (fn [] state))
(defn- sub-3 [state] (fn [] state))

(defn strawberry []
  (let [state (r/subscribe [:totoro])]
    (fn []
      [sub-1 @state]
      [sub-2 @state]
      [sub-3 @state])))
```

Comment: Why are you using multiple subscriptions in the first place? re-frame is going to recognize they are all identical and combine them. I don't think there is nearly enough information here to figure out what you are trying to accomplish.